# How can I share the filesystem between host and container with Docker Compose?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I want to develop a WordPress theme, and I am using docker compose to avoid the installation of Apache and MySQL on my computer.

I need to share the filesystem between the host and container to edit the content of WordPress' wp-themes directory.

This is my docker-compose.yml file, taken from docker's documentation page. I already added the volumes directive to WordPress' service:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
        - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

No files are created in `./themes` directory when I run the command `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: There are no obvious errors.  1. Can you hit the website? Can you tail the logs 'docker compose logs -f wordpress'.  My best guess is that is taking longer to start than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can have the full path:

```
     volumes:
    - /my/user/home/directory/wordpress_docker/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
```

or you could have just:

```
     volumes:
    - ${PWD}/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
```

Comment: I tgink you are confusing docker (no relative paths allowed) with docker-compose (relative paths allowed)?